# How to Search Facebook hashtags with GraphApi

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

I only want to search for all public posts with a specified Hashtag in it. For example i want to find all public posts with the Hashtag "#covid" in a specified timespan of 1 Year. Can i handle that with the normal Graph API of Facebook.

Comment: No there is no API for that.

Comment: Ok, I will try to use Instagram Graph API Hashtag Search instead. There is any step by step tutorial to do that. Ex. how to make screen recording to search for hashtags, why I need to use Facebook login for another users. I'm a beginner in this topic.

Comment: There is documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/